# Access a member in a struct via a variable in C++

Tags: c++

I have a struct with two members, for example:

```
struct DataSet {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

..., and i have to access those in a method, but only one at a time, for example:

```
void foo(StructMember dsm) { // ("StructMember" does not exist)
    DataSet ds;
    ds.x = 4;
    ds.y = 6;

    std::cout << ds.dsm * ds.dsm << std::endl;
}
```

```
foo(x);
foo(y);
```

Output i wish to have:

```
16
36
```

What should I do when I have to solve a problem like this? Is there a data type which can access a member?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is you could use pointer arithmetic. You could pass as the struct "member" an offset relative to the beginning of the struct. This would be dependent on the size of the members. With ints I think you can guarantee they'd be aligned to word boundaries, so you'd pass `dsm = 0` to access `x` and `dsm = 4` to access `y`, then you'd access them like `int val = int(*(&ds+dsm))`.

Comment: @ocket8888 `c++` has pointer-to-members, so no need for custom pointer hacks to make this work.

Comment: @eerorika You are right. Previously I had two strings as members, but I changed them to int's. I have forgotten to remove the "std::".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use a pointer-to-member. The syntax for the type is `TypeOfMember TypeOfStruct::*`, and to access you do `struct_variable.*pointer_variable`

```cpp
using StructMember = int DataSet::*;  // Pointer to a member of `DataSet` of type `int`

void foo(StructMember dsm) {
    DataSet ds;
    ds.x = 4;
    ds.y = 6;

    std::cout << ds.*dsm * ds.*dsm << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    foo(&DataSet::x);
    foo(&DataSet::y);
}
```